# Getting Files from huge Directorys on NetDrives

Tags: c#

i need to get Files from a Directory on a NetDrive. The Problem is that this Dir could contains 500k File or more.

The normal ways:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"L:\cs\fromSQL\Data", "*.dat",
                                   SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

or

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"L:\cs\fromSQL\Data");
            var files = 
                dir.GetFiles("*.dat", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

are taking way to long. They always parse the whole Directory.

Example: NetDrive-Directory Containg ~130k Files, the first option takes 15 Minutes.

Is there a way to get just a number of files (for example the oldest one's) or something other thats faster?

Thanks!
Greetings
Christoph

Comment: You would still have to call GetFiles to get a count. There might be another way but I don't know of it. I'm guessing Directory.EnumerateFiles would take just as long.

Comment: Yes your right, but i dont really need a count luckily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a try on  [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232.aspx)

As msdn says :-

```
Returns an enumerable collection of file information in the current directory.
```

it is IEnumerable ,so it can stream entries rather than buffer them all

For example :-

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)) {
    // ...
}
```

More details on MSDN :-

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   FileInfo objects before the whole collection is returned; when you use
>   GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to be
>   returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more
>   efficient.

Comment: thx! Since i used .Net3.5 for testing that, i wasnt able to find these Version 4 Functions (

Answer (score 2):

Use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead:

```
var count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"L:\cs\fromSQL\Data", "*.dat",
                               SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Count();
```

If you want to filter some files, then use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` and filter the files using `Where`:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"L:\cs\fromSQL\Data");
var count = di.EnumerateFiles("*.dat",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
           .Where(file => /* your condition */)
           .Count();
```

Comment: You beat me by 7 seconds!!

Comment: thx for your answer!

But actually from my tests you are just half right. If i use some Further Linq-Expressions like OrderBy or Where the program starts do grap the whole list first. This is even slower than GetFiles than.